# How to write a python function that receives a list of function name-strings to evaluate, and stacks each function's output into one DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dataframe

I have 3 Python functions (full-on `def` functions) that each output a 2d numpy array (row vector) of the same size as one another. These functions are alternative approaches/answers to some same core problem.

```
def fun1():
    return row_array
```

An identifier name (a string) corresponds to each of these functions, so that a full list of these function names would be

```
names = ['fun1','fun2','fun3']
```

How can I attach these names to the corresponding functions quickly as a `pandas.DataFrame`?

```
all = pd.DataFrame([['fun1', fun1], ['fun2', fun2]])
```

Finally, I would like to write a master function that lets the user send  to it a list of names of desired functions to call, which could be all or a subset of them, and this master function evaluates each called function only, and stacks their respective `row_array`s on top of each other into a squarish `pandas DataFrame`. In other words, aggregate all *desired* "alternative answers" into one data structure for viewing, so that at any later time I can repeat with a different subset of names.

What's the most efficient way to do all of the above without a series of `if name is in list` conditions?